# Not wanting promises to swallow errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm switching some code from bluebird to native Promises and am getting rather annoyed at the fact that native promises swallow errors even when there's not a `.catch()` defined.  It makes debugging *impossible* unless you put a `catch()` on *every* promise.

So my question -- Does anyone have a solution to this?  Possibilities include some way to tell promises to throw, or a way to globally catch them, or...?

Comment: Bluebird does "swallow" errors just as well… Do you mean that your native promise implementation (which one?) does not emit `unhandledRejection` events? Well, choose a different implementation then.

Comment: @Bergi - Neither node `v0.12` nor IO `2.4.0` do anything with unhandled rejections, making them effectively unusable.  I'm looking for a solution other than "use something else".  Bluebird doesn't throw, but it logs errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote and Petka (bluebird's author) implemented (we had help :)) this functionality for Node a little back. I don't think you should switch from bluebird (it's faster and has a richer API) but if you want - use the rejection hooks:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(p, reason) {
    // handle error here, all "swallowed" errors get here
});
```

This requires io.js 1.4+ or modern NodeJS (3.0+), this won't work in node 0.12, so better use a modern version or just keep using bluebird (which is also compatible with this event)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm switching a few things from bluebird that are being sent to browsers.  I polyfill with bluebird, but the lib is way to heavy to send by default.  I have other issues using Node 3.0+ right now, primarily around NaN 2.0, but if you say this works on io 1.4-3 I think ~2.4 will work for both of these.  Thanks :)

Comment: If you encounter any issues please open an issue and we will fix them. We feel your pain, code on :)

Comment: @zyklus: What do you mean by "sent to browsers"? Are you looking for a clientside library?

Comment: @Bergi -- No, I have a good amount of code that runs in both node and bundled js.  I'm stripping bluebird from that code so that I can use the native `Promise` object when it's available and not need a client-side lib at all.